# Display ellipsis with onclick ability to show content only for long content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to shorten long paragraph to show only a single line with showing "ellipsis" (of a sort) at the end (using CSS, JS, JQuery...), but there are three additional conditions I find hard to fulfill:

- There should be on-click event on the ellipsis that shows and hides
  remaining content (this is relatively easy with bunch of tutorials
  on the internet)
- The ellipsis should look like a button (i.e. not plain-text "...",
  ideally stand-alone html element)
- The ellipsis should be visible if and **only if** the content is too
  long to display on single line (this is the part I struggle with)

Here is fiddle of almost what I want: https://jsfiddle.net/Drecker/3gv4tkL9/2/ with the first two conditions fulfilled, but I need the second ellipsis (shown with red text) to not be displayed (as the corresponding text is short enough to fit on single line).

On the other hand I am able to use CSS `text-overflow: ellipsis` parameter but in such case, I am not able to make the ellipsis clickable and change its layout.

**Edit:** To clarify, the data (text of the paragraphs) are dynamically loaded (fetched from internal service, processed via Vue.js, and displayed via `v-for`), so I can not just render the page, look which rows are too long and remove the buttons from such rows. I tried to make the code in the fiddle as easy to read as possible so I avoided calling external service to load the texts and using Vue.js

Comment: It would be nice if you can share the reason for the downvote, so I can avoid doing the same mistake again

Answer (score 1):

Remove this from the code for all the text that is short enough and doesn't need an ellipsis button:

```
  <button class="ellipsis" style="color: red">
    Show
  </button>
```

Posting some of your code will help out

Comment: The thing is that the page is not static (the text for the page is loaded from DB), so I can not tell so easily which text will be short enough and which will be too long. As for the code: is there anything particular you are missing in the fiddle?

Comment: The fiddle you've linked to is static and you're asking for help on a dynamically loaded page you're developing. How are you fetching the data? The more you provide, the easier it is to help out.

Comment: The data is loaded via JQuery request to another internal service, subsequently it is processed via Vue.js and displayed. I tried to keep the fiddle as simple as possible, so I avoid calling additional services (and using vue) as I did not see how it would be helpful with the presentation side of things.

Comment: It's almost like you need to iterate through your dataset and check the length of each item being retreived. Then if it's above a certain length append a class to the item. Set up a CSS class to handle the ellipsis button and expanding. That sound about right?

Comment: That could be one approach. The (one) problem here is that I do now know how to check the length of the element (you cant do that based on the number of characters as "i" has different length than "m"), and fetching it via JQuery is also problematic as its width is set to flex to parent element. Would you mind sharing the code if you are able to solve the problem?

Comment: Are you truncating the elements if the browser width goes below a certain measure, regardless of text length?

Comment: The width of the container element (with the text) is actually dynamically changed based on the width of the browser, however there is minimal width set. So if the text is very short (i.e. one word, which is possible), whole text will fit in this minimal width and wont get truncated.